# SQL Update query product cart

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  ProductId   MemberId    SessionId      CreatedOn    Quantity
62  1           2                          2012-09-11   1
63  2           2                          2012-09-11   1
64  1           0   agzdeoqubwokfme05wwmne55   2012-09-11   1
65  3           0   agzdeoqubwokfme05wwmne55   2012-09-11   1
```

I have above table and I need to make one procedure.
My scenario is without login add item to cart and when you login merge all items.

I will pass two parameter in procedure @MemberId (Login Member Id), @SessionID

And I want out put table like below.

```
ID  ProductId   MemberId    SessionId      CreatedOn    Quantity
62  1           2                          2012-09-11   2
63  2           2                          2012-09-11   1
65  3           2                              2012-09-11   1
```

One product merges with another product and makes quantity 2. And that row should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL SERVER 2005 or above

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT , ProductId INT,  MemberId INT,   SessionId VARCHAR(100),  CreatedOn DATETIME,   Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO #T SELECT 62,1 ,2 ,' ','2012-09-11',1
INSERT INTO #T SELECT 63,  2,2, ' ','2012-09-11',1
INSERT INTO #T SELECT 64,  1,0,'agzdeoqubwokfme05wwmne55','2012-09-11',1
INSERT INTO #T SELECT 65,  3,0,'agzdeoqubwokfme05wwmne55','2012-09-11',1

;With CTE AS 
(SELECT 
    ID
    ,ProductId
    ,MemberId = MAX(MemberId) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1))
    ,SessionID
    ,CreatedOn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(CreatedOn) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1)),20)
    ,Quantity = SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1))
    ,Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1))
FROM #T)

SELECT ID,ProductId,MemberId,SessionID,CreatedOn,Quantity FROM CTE WHERE Rn = 1

DROP TABLE #T
```

will give the result as

```
ID  ProductId   MemberId    SessionID              CreatedOn    Quantity
62  1            2                                  2012-09-11    2
63  2            2                                  2012-09-11    1
65  3            0          agzdeoqubwokfme05wwmne55 2012-09-11   1
```

Finally if you want to update the table, the here you go

```
UPDATE #T
SET 
    #T.ID = c.ID
    ,#T.ProductId =c.ProductId
    ,#T.MemberId = c.MemberId
    ,#T.SessionID = c.SessionID
    ,#T.CreatedOn = c.CreatedOn
    ,#T.Quantity = c.Quantity
FROM #T
INNER JOIN CTE c
ON #T.ID = c.ID
WHERE c.Rn = 1
```

The result is

```
ID  ProductId   MemberId    SessionId               CreatedOn   Quantity
62  1              2                                 2012-09-11   2
63  2              2                                 2012-09-11   1
64  1              0    agzdeoqubwokfme05wwmne5      2012-09-11   1
65  3              0    agzdeoqubwokfme05wwmne55     2012-09-11   1
```

The complete query is

```
;With CTE AS 
(SELECT 
    ID
    ,ProductId
    ,MemberId = MAX(MemberId) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1))
    ,SessionID
    ,CreatedOn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(CreatedOn) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1)),20)
    ,Quantity = SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1))
    ,Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER bY(SELECT 1))
FROM #T)

UPDATE #T
SET 
    #T.ID = c.ID
    ,#T.ProductId =c.ProductId
    ,#T.MemberId = c.MemberId
    ,#T.SessionID = c.SessionID
    ,#T.CreatedOn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),c.CreatedOn,20)
    ,#T.Quantity = c.Quantity
FROM #T
INNER JOIN CTE c
ON #T.ID = c.ID
WHERE c.Rn = 1

SELECT * FROM #T

DROP TABLE #T
```

**For Any Version of SQL**

```
UPDATE #T
SET 
    #T.ID = c.ID
    ,#T.ProductId =c.ProductId
    ,#T.MemberId = c.MemberId
    ,#T.SessionID = c.SessionID
    ,#T.CreatedOn = c.CreatedOn
    ,#T.Quantity = c.Quantity
FROM #T
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.ID,t.ProductID,t.MemberId,t.SessionId,t.CreatedOn,x.Quantity
            FROM #T t 
            JOIN (
                    SELECT
                            ID = MIN(ID)
                            ,ProductID 
                            ,MemberId = MAX(MemberId)       
                            ,CreatedOn = MAX(CreatedOn)
                            ,Quantity = SUM(Quantity) 
                    FROM #T 
                    GROUP BY ProductID
                    )X
            ON t.ID =X.ID) c
ON #T.ID = c.ID


SELECT * FROM #T
DROP TABLE #T
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ProductID, 
       max(MemberId), 
       max(CreatedOn),
       sum(Quantity) 
FROM theTable 
WHERE SessionID=<id> or MemberID=<id>
GROUP BY ProductID
```

Comment: you answer is perfect for me but I need little bit more help how do I update this table with it? and member Id column is black for last record.

Answer (score 1):

Updating may not be the optimum solution, it may be better to delete all the records  and insert new ones.

Anyhow you need to do something like this if you want to update and then delete the extra ones.

Assuming `ID` is the unique key here. Here is complete logic, read carefully

```
DECLARE @Temp1 TABLE 
(
--datafields same AS your table

)

DECLARE @Temp2 TABLE 
(
--datafields same AS your table
)

INSERT INTO @Temp1
SELECT ID,
       ProductID, 
       MemberId,
       SessionId, 
       CreatedOn,
       Quantity 
FROM theTable 
WHERE SessionID= @SessionID  or MemberID= @MemberID 

UPDATE a
SET SessionID =  @SessionID  , MemberID= @MemberID 
FROM @Temp1 AS a
--WHERE  SessionID= @SessionID  OR MemberID= @MemberID 

INSERT INTO @Temp2
SELECT MAX(ID),
       ProductID, 
       max(MemberId),
       MAX(SessionId),
       max(CreatedOn),
       sum(Quantity) 
FROM @Temp1
GROUP BY ProductID 

UPDATE a
SET a.MemberId = b.MemberId ,a.SessionId=b.SessionId ,a.CreatedOn=b.CreatedOn,a.Quantity=b.Quantity 
FROM YourTable AS a
INNER JOIN @Temp2 AS b
ON a.ID=b.ID      

DELETE  FROM YourTable
WHERE   ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                    FROM    @Temp1 AS ta
                    WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                         FROM   @Temp2 AS tb
                                         WHERE  ta.ID = tb.ID ) )
```